# Possible to run Windows Update Server on FreeNAS?

Tags: windows-update, freebsd, freenas

Like the title says...  Is there any way to run a Windows Update Server as a jail or something like that?  Preferably I'd like to keep FreeNAS as the host OS.  I don't think my box is powerful enough to run virtualised (HP mini server).

Comment: Would running the database and file hosting on the FreeNAS and having another computer running the WSUS Software be acceptable? Also installing only a [Core install of windows server](http://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/wsus-on-windows-server-2012-core-from-scratch/) should not take up too many resources.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I could run windows server on virtualbox on one of my workstations and keep the updates on the NAS.  That would work.  But if I was to do a windows core server install on the NAS how would that be done?  Dual boot (FreeNAS and Windows Server) comes to mind, but having WSUS running as a VM under FreeNAS would be very cool.  I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

A jail by itself will not work, because that is still a FreeBSD environment.

But before trying virualization, you should try [wine](http://www.winehq.org/). In the wine app database, [there is at least one mention of WSUS](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3609).
So running WSUS under wine in a jail might work.

If all else fails, you can always run windows server under virtualbox or qemu.

Comment: Virtualbox would be good but would it be easy to setup on FreeNAS?  From what I am reading FreeNAS is not really designed for installing whatever additional software you like.  That's what jails are used for.  Maybe Ubuntu server would be a better (easier) platform to run Virutalbox.  Failing that a dual boot (FreeNAS/Windows Server) might be the easiest and most robust solution.

Comment: You can just [install stuff using ports](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Installing_non-PBI_Software#Compiling_FreeBSD_Ports_with_make).